# Почему не работает onmousemove с style.transform?

Tags: javascript

Есть текущая задача заставить серый круг следовать за курсом мыши внутри красного квадрата.

Попробовал реализовать с помощью события onmousemove и style.transform. событие срабатывает, а вот style.transform вместе с функцией нет. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно реализовать задачу.

```js
let eye = document.querySelector('.circle');




document.onmousemove = function (event) {
  let x = event.x;
  let y = event.y;
  console.log(x + '' + y);
  eye.style.transform = 'rotate(' + 57.2958 * arcctg(x,y)+'deg)';
  function arcctg(x, y) {
  return Math.PI / 2 - Math.atan(x / y );
}
}
```

```css
.conatiner {
  width: 800px;
}
.eye {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ff5b40;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="eye">
  <div class="circle">
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а почему ты думаешь, что transform не работает?

Comment: Не нравится как круг вращается? Угол поворота не немного смещен по часовой стрелке? Если радиус скругления убавить, то заметнее будет: https://jsfiddle.net/bLejk1g5/